# Android populate listview with cursor

Tags: java, android

My app uses a simple `SQLite` database. Everything works fine I can now present a `Toast` with a chosen row from the return query using:

```
{
    //etc etc etc...

    c.movetofirst();
    DisplayTitle(c);
}
public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
{
    Toast.makeText(main.this, 
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
            "reg: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
            "type: " + c.getString(2) + "\n",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}
```

I want to prsent all the data in the cursor to the screen using a view but I am not sure how to go about this. Which view should I use? I just wnt a simple looking grid representation which allows me to scroll through each row in the cursor

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I show ALL rows in the Cursor?

There are several ways if you are working with a `Cursor`, for example see the "moveTo" related methods, here's an example:

```
Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(c.getCount());
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
               Item i = new Item(select(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2));
               set.add(i);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
         }
         if (!c.isClosed()) {
            c.close();
         }
```

This assumes `Item` is a data class that has a constructor with three `String` parameters. Going with your code, id, reg, and type. Usually column 0 will be a numeric ID (not getString, but SQLite uses "manifest typing" so it will sort of dyna-type a String/Long from column 0 -- you may want to AUTOINCREMENT and use getLong there though).

One you have a collection of items, you can do anything you want with them to display them. If you want a scrolling/selectable list, then `ListView` is an excellent choice. And, you can back it with a `CursorAdapter`.

Here's an example of a `ListView` that is populated by a `CursorAdapter` from an open source project: http://code.google.com/p/and-bookworm/source/browse/trunk/src/com/totsp/bookworm/Main.java (see the inner `BookCursorAdapter` class, it should get you pointed in the right direction).

Comment: I already have a method for populating the cursor with all rows in the table, what I am asking for is how to present this to the screen. I want to use a view to present all data in the cursor onto the screen. sorry If i was not very clear!

Comment: I updated the answer, after you updated the question ;). If you want a simple looking scrollable "grid," and you already have the Cursor, then ListView/CursorAdapter is the ticket.

Comment: Thanks you for the link im taking a look